# How to do the live streaming of external webcam using webRTC on MacBook Pro

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, webrtc

I have to create a live streaming video application in which I have to read the video using the external web camera connected to my MacBook. I have to do this using WebRTC. But while executing the code the integrated webcam get triggered instead of the external webcam.

```
var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");
var constraints = { audio:true,video: { facingMode:"environment" } 

var promise = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);

promise.then(function(mediaStream) {

  video.srcObject = mediaStream;

  video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
    video.play();
  };
})
.catch(function(err) {

  console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);


 });
```

How can I trigger the external webcam connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/ is the canonical example of how to select devices, demonstrating enumerateDevices() and getUserMedia()

Comment: I don't see otg webcam show up as one the video inputs .  I only see embedded smartphone cameras from and back but not the one connected to the microusv port via otg cable

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API

And this one https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API/Constraints

```
if (typeof MediaStreamTrack === 'undefined'){
  alert('This browser does not support MediaStreamTrack.\n\nTry Chrome Canary.');
} else {
  MediaStreamTrack.getSources( onSourcesAcquired);
}

function onSourcesAcquired(sources) {
  for (var i = 0; i != sources.length; ++i) {
    var source = sources[i];
    // source.id -> DEVICE ID
    // source.label -> DEVICE NAME
    // source.kind = "audio" OR "video"
    // TODO: add this to some datastructure of yours or a selection dialog
  }
}

....

constraints = {
  audio: {
    optional: [{sourceId: selected_audio_source_id}]
  },
  video: {
    optional: [{sourceId: selected_video_source_id}]
  }
};
navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback);
```